# Fail to push docker image to docker hub with Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-registry

Referred to this youtube tutorial to build docker image and push it to docker hub using Jenkins

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z32yzy4TrKM

Basically it polls from github (https://github.com/miltonchandradas/dockerwebapp) and run the jenkinsfile inside.

Everything works fine for me except the last step to push the image to docker hub.

The Jenkinsfile is like that

```
node {

    checkout scm

    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'dockerHub') {

        def customImage = docker.build("miltonc/dockerwebapp")

        /* Push the container to the custom Registry */
        customImage.push()
    }
}
```

I use the same Jenkinsfile and I have created my own docker hub credential named dockerHub already, but still got the following error

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I wonder if I should not build the image named miltonc/dockerwebapp which duplicate the original image from the writer?

Any idea how I should change it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `https://registry.hub.docker.com` is the old reference that was used.

Use `registry.docker.io` or `registry-1.docker.io` instead of `registry.hub.docker.com` I think `hub.docker.com`  `index.docker.io` will do it as well.

In the [Docker uptime status page](https://status.docker.com/) you will see that those two domains are monitored, and the domain named as the "registry".

Unfortunately Docker doesn't state what is the actual domain as they are many that do the same.

Comment: Thanks Vad1mo. I have fixed it. Turns out I need put my docker id into the name of the image tag, i.e. docker.build("<mydockerid>/<anydockerappname>")

Answer (score 0):

You need provide the registry hostname if pushing to private repositories
See here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/#tag-an-image-for-a-private-registry